# Unable to get the dictionary based on the first value of the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary is this format. This is a spark representation :

```
[4401188189705 -> [4.0, 1.0], 44011125835787 -> [5.0, 1.0], 44011142622982 -> [12.0, 1.0], 4401192401665 -> [7.0, 1.0], 4401171339786 -> [5.0, 1.0]]
```

I am trying to sort it in the descending order of the first value of the dictionary. But unable to do so. My code is as follows.

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(distribution.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][0], reverse=True))
```

Expected output :

```
 44011142622982 -> [12.0, 1.0], 4401192401665 -> [7.0, 1.0], 4401171339786 -> [5.0, 1.0],44011125835787 -> [5.0, 1.0],[4401188189705 -> [4.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: I am using python 3.7.10

Comment: You code [works fine](https://www.online-python.com/kq0PnOIUVo), using a dict of your spark data.

Comment: Dicts aren't really ordered data structures per se. While newer Python versions will remember insertion order in dicts, they're generally the wrong data structure for ordered data. You should at least be using an `OrderedDict` explicitly.